# How to check for null current user in Firebase for Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-provider

**Objective**

I am trying to display the name of a currently logged in user in my flutter app screen. If no user is currently logged in from this device, then a blanck would appear. This name is stored in a String variable called `userName`. Also, if a user is logged in, a boolean `isSignedIn` variable will be set to true, else it'll be false.

**My code**:

In the *firebase_auth_methods.dart* file I have the following code:

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth;

//STATE PERSISTANCE
Stream<User?> get authState => FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();

//GET USER
User get user => _auth.currentUser!;
```

In my *account_screen.dart* file I have the following code in Widget build():

```
final currUser = context.read<FirebaseAuthMethods>().user;

    print(currUser);
    if (!currUser.isAnonymous && currUser.phoneNumber == null) {
      userName = currUser.email!;
      isSignedIn = true;
    }
    if (currUser.phoneNumber != null) {
      userName = currUser.phoneNumber!;
      isSignedIn = true;
    }
    if (currUser.isAnonymous) {
      isSignedIn = true;
    }

    if (currUser == null) {
      userName = "Guest";
      isSignedIn = false;
    }
```

**Issue faced**:

However, I am unable to check for a possible null value of `currUser` as I am receiving the warning: **The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.
Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement.**

When no user is logged in from this emulator AVD/device, navigating to the *account_screen* is returning **Null check operator is used on a null value** error.

I seem to understand why I am getting this error, but don't know how to perform the required validation check for the null value of `currUser`. This is my first time of trying my hand at Firebase Authentication, so please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the '!' sign from the getter:

```
User? get user => _auth.currentUser!; <--- here, and make the return type nullable.
```

And now when you read the user with:

```
final currUser = context.read<FirebaseAuthMethods>().user;
```

It will be nullable.
You got the error because you forced the user non-nullable with the !.

Comment: I have updated the code to: `User? get user => _auth.currentUser;`. But I'm getting the following errors now: Error: Property 'isAnonymous' cannot be accessed on 'User?' because it is potentially null.

Comment: This is because `isAnonymous` can be null. You have to check first if the user is null

Comment: @quoci how do I do that? When I do `if(currUser == null)` I'm getting **The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false. Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement.** warning.

Comment: Ok, I have first checked if `currUser` is null and displayed guest details. Then later I've put the if statements for isAnonymous and email within a parent if statement that checks for `currUser` being not null. This serves my purpose now.

Answer (score 0):

in your class for user, create a getter for bool if user is empty or not.

```
  class User {

  final String id;
  final String? email;
  final String? name;
  final String? photo;

  static const empty = User(id: '');

  bool get isEmpty => this == User.empty;

  bool get isNotEmpty => this != User.empty;

  const User({
    required this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.photo
});
}
```

the logic here is if user id, or uid is empty or equal to `''`, then there is no user

and you can use it like this :

```
final currUser = context.read<FirebaseAuthMethods>().user;
if (currUser.isEmpty) {
      userName = "Guest";
      isSignedIn = false;
    }
```

Comment: `User` class is not mine, it is a part of the FirebaseAth.instance

Comment: you dont need a model from your own user? like custom data your store in firestrore for example?